# Rotating image does not sit well in parent container

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, css-transforms

I created a directive to rotate and resize (scale) an image.  I am currently accomplishing this by manipulating in-line styling of the element.  I am using css transforms (`rotate` and `scale`).

My current approach for rotating the image is to rotate it about the top left corner as the origin, then I shift the image back into view with margins.  For scaling, I also recalculate the new effective dimensions of the image by multiplying the original dimensions by the scaling factor.

I have the scaling and rotation working, but non-standard rotations don't sit within the parent container well.  For example, when rotated 180 degrees, the image has a bunch of extra whitespace below it, which extends the div it's in for no apparent reason.

The directive:

```
function directive()  {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            options: '='
        },
        link: link
    };

    function link(scope, element, attributes) {
        element.bind('load', function()  {
            if (!scope.options.originalSize) {
                element.removeAttr('style'); //clear all previous styling

                //workaround for IE (it's dumb, and I'd rather just use this element (element[0]) data)
                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src = element[0].src;
                scope.options.originalSize = {
                    height: img.height,
                    width: img.width
                };
                scope.options.scaling = 1.0;
                scope.options.rotation = 0;
            }
            transformWithCss();
        });

        scope.$watch('options.rotation', transformWithCss);
        scope.$watch('options.scaling', transformWithCss);

        function transformWithCss()  {
            if (!scope.options || !scope.options.originalSize)
                return;

            var width = scope.options.originalSize.width * scope.options.scaling;
            var height = scope.options.originalSize.height * scope.options.scaling;
            var marginTop, marginLeft;

            var effectiveRotation = (scope.options.rotation % 360 + 360) % 360;
            switch (effectiveRotation) {
                case 0:
                    marginTop = 0;
                    marginLeft = 0;
                    break;
                case 90:
                    marginTop = 0;
                    marginLeft = height * scope.options.scaling;
                    break;
                case 180:
                    marginTop = height * scope.options.scaling;
                    marginLeft = width * scope.options.scaling;
                    break;
                case 270:
                    marginTop = width * scope.options.scaling;
                    marginLeft = 0;
                    break;
                default:
                    //how did we get here? throw exception?
                    alert("something went wrong with rotation");
                    break;
            }

            element.css({
                "transform": 'scale(' + scope.options.scaling + ') rotate(' + scope.options.rotation + 'deg) ',
                "width": width + 'px',
                "height": height + 'px',
                "transform-origin": '0px 0px',
                "margin-top": marginTop + 'px',
                "margin-left": marginLeft + 'px'
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Usage in HTML:

```
<div class="parent-div col-md-10 col-lg-10">
  <p>Some other content</p>
  <div class="image-holder">
    <img scaling-rotating-image="" options="ctrl.imageOptions" src="//lorempixel.com/500/300/cats/" />
  </div>
</div>
```

A [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/JIEw8a9Yvq6tAjp8XNNe?p=preview).  Notice the different colored borders.

Why does my directive not handle rotation gracefully?  Why does its parent div do really weird stuff when resizing?

Comment: have you considered using absolute positioning on the image, such that whitespace is not affected? Note that if this approach is taken, then you'll have to handle "image-holder" sizing because absolute positioning will remove it's respective element from document flow.

Comment: @Todd thanks for the help.  If you have the time to post an answer, that would be great.  I got it working thanks to that suggestion.  If not, I'll just answer my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Todd's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33920634/rotating-image-does-not-sit-well-in-parent-container?noredirect=1#comment55602552_33920634), I solved my weird whitespacing issues by using **`position: absolute`**.  To compensate for this, I also had to redimension the parent container.  Here's the updated `transformWithCss` function:

```
function transformWithCss()  {
    if (!scope.options || !scope.options.originalSize)
        return;

    var width = scope.options.originalSize.width * scope.options.scaling;
    var height = scope.options.originalSize.height * scope.options.scaling;
    var marginTop, marginLeft;
    var parentHeight, parentWidth; //to redimension the parent container

    var effectiveRotation = (scope.options.rotation % 360 + 360) % 360;
    switch (effectiveRotation) {
        case 0:
            parentHeight = height * scope.options.scaling;
            parentWidth = width * scope.options.scaling;
            marginTop = 0;
            marginLeft = 0;
            break;
        case 90:
            parentHeight = width * scope.options.scaling;
            parentWidth = height * scope.options.scaling;
            marginTop = 0;
            marginLeft = parentWidth;
            break;
        case 180:
            parentHeight = height * scope.options.scaling;
            parentWidth = width * scope.options.scaling;
            marginTop = parentHeight;
            marginLeft = parentWidth;
            break;
        case 270:
            parentHeight = width * scope.options.scaling;
            parentWidth = height * scope.options.scaling;
            marginTop = parentHeight;
            marginLeft = 0;
            break;
        default:
            //how did we get here? throw exception?
            alert("something went wrong with rotation");
            break;
    }

    element.css({
        "position": "absolute", //absolute positions removes weird whitespace
        "transform": 'scale(' + scope.options.scaling + ') rotate(' + scope.options.rotation + 'deg) ',
        "width": width + 'px',
        "height": height + 'px',
        "transform-origin": '0px 0px',
        "margin-top": marginTop + 'px',
        "margin-left": marginLeft + 'px'
    });

    //redimension parent container
    element.parent().css({
        "height": parentHeight + 'px',
        "width": parentWidth + 'px'
    });

}
```

Updated working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IjmB3exmjlSgkRLdm3TX?p=preview).